# Must abstract methods be given a definition in a class or in an interface?

Tags: java, abstract-class

I thought in an interface, we usually explain what the method will do. And then in a class which implements the interface, we just write the implementation for the method. So, I thought we will provide the definition for an abstract method in the interface, but I am not sure. If you know the answer, please explain in in detail.

Comment: This question is a little bit vague.  What do you mean by "explain what the method will do"?  An interface doesn't describe anything other than the public API.

Comment: You must really go through this : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 1):

Definition and implementation are synonymous. A method's definition is its implementation.

Abstract methods don't have definitions/implementations, they are only *declared*. A declaration lists the method's name, parameters, and return type, but does not include the method body.

```
interface I {
    // Declaration
    void method(int arg);
}

class C implements I {
    // Definition
    public void method(int arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An interface defines the required behavior of classes that implement it. The interface is meant to define:

- The signature of the method
- What the method's result is

You can imagine the interface as the "user-side" of the implementation. The user wants to know: What does this method do? What can I expect? How do I call it? The user doesn't care how it's done, only that he gets the expected result.

Implementing method define the *implementation* of the method. It's the class's job to figure out how the goal is going to be accomplished. Different implementing classes can achieve the same result using different means.

Thus, to summarize, the interface defines the method signature, and the implementing class defines the method body.

Answer (score 0):

Definition is the same as implementation. In an interface, you only declare the abstract method. That means you specify the signature of the method, and what it returns. You do not define, how it works.

For eg

```
public interface Draw
{
  public void drawCircle(int radius);
}
```

Here we only declare drawCircle() method, specifying what are the input parameters and what will be the output.

The actual implementation is specified in the class implementing the interface

```
public class DrawTool implements Draw
{
 public void drawCircle(int radius)
{
  // Give the logic for drawing Circle.
}
}
```

So here you are defining the Abstract Method drawCircle() in the class, the logic for drawing the circle.